# Can not restore snapshot in Xcode 5.0(error: "DVTSnapshotsTmp is in invalid")

Tags: xcode

I can not restore a snapshot from Xcode (5.0).  "DVTSnapshotsTmp is in invalid" Message attached. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snapshot is probably corrupt.

From my experience, when you try and restore a corrupt snapshot the restore process fails and gives you the DVTSnapshotsTmp error when you try to restore ANY snapshot.

To get rid of this certain error just search for the DVTSnapshotsTmp folder (with something like Find Any File) to get a path similar to this:

/private/var/folders/8y/42wn054s541g91y4qxg5dyd80000gn/T/DVTSnapshotsTmp

This should allow you to restore the penultimate or other earlier snapshots, but probably not the corrupt one. And all the new snapshots you make will probably be corrupt too. Getting around this is a whole another story. I've written a brief [blog post](http://www.goloskok.com/dev/?p=6) about it if that is what you are after.